# dictionary trygetvalue null

Tags: c#, dictionary, nullreferenceexception

```
 private Dictionary<Type, Bag<Event>> events = new Dictionary<Type, Bag<Event>>();

 internal Bag<T> GetEventList<T>() where T:class
 {
    Type type = typeof(T);
    Bag<Event> b;
    if (events.TryGetValue(type, out b))
    {
        return b as Bag<T>;
    }
    else {
        b = new Bag<T>() as Bag<Event>;
        events[type] = b;
        return b as Bag<T>;
    }
}

internal void AddEvent<T>(T ev) where T:class,Event
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    Bag<Event> b;
    if (events.TryGetValue(type, out b))
    {
        b.Add(ev); // <= NullReferenceException, b is null
    }
    else {
        b = new Bag<T>() as Bag<Event>;
        events.Add(type, b);
        b.Add(ev);
    }
}
```

I always get a NullReferenceException inside AddEvent.
The events Dictionary is used only in those two functions, 
I have no idea why the value is null... I'm not inserting null values anywhere!

I'm going nuts here...

Comment: because your `Bag<Event> b;` is null in the dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure `b = new Bag<T>() as Bag<Event>;` is not `null`?

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are calling, as well as any type hierarchy surrounding `Event`?

Answer (score 4):

The likely culprit is this line:

```
b = new Bag<T>() as Bag<Event>;
```

The `as` cast is probably failing, which will assign `null` to `b`.

My guess would be that you are using a subclass of `Event` as the type of `T`, and since `Bag<T>` is not covariant on the type parameter (I assume it's a class, so it can't be,) the cast fails, and you end up with `b` being `null`.

**Update**: Based on the comment below, the issue is indeed the `as` cast. To fix things up, just create a `new Bag<Event>()`, no cast required.

Comment: Wouldn't it throw another NullReferenceException in the last b.Add(ev); if this was the case?

Comment: @LimoWanKenobi I can only speculate, since we've not been shown the calling code, but I would guess that the initial call uses `Event` as the generic argument, but subsequent calls do not. Another possibility is that the `GetEventList()` call happens first, but the type isn't found in the dictionary, so the `as` cast in that method results in null, leading to the nullref the next time add is called for the given type. Regardless of the actual sequence, it's very likely that the `as` cast is the issue.

Comment: In the first method, `GetEventList`, he also uses the `as` operator, and he also adds to the `Dictionary<,>` there! He just does it using the setter of the indexer. And that method doesn't even constrain its `T` to be an `Event`. **Alejandro**, never use the `as` operator unless it's OK with you that the result might be `null`. If you're not prepared to handle `null`, use a "hard" cast instead. In your code, what's the relation between `T` and `Event`?

Comment: -Ok, let's see. In my code "Event" is an interface, and T implements that interface.
-I added some breakpoints and GetEventList() is not called before AddEvent()
-I'll remove the 'as' casts and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: @dlev Calling code: (CellsChangedEvent implements Event)
    `world.SystemManager.AddEvent(new CellsChangedEvent(entity));`

Comment: @AlejandroGuillen So the suspicion is correct: `Bag<CellsChangedEvent> as Bag<Event>;` will result in `null`. (Also, if `Event` is an interface, you should name it `IEvent`.) To fix this, just create a `new Bag<Event>()`, no cast needed.

Comment: Yes, thank you. 
Something to do with covariance-contracovariance, and since I dont know what that is I'm just going to stay away from generics for now.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere a null is being associated with the key type.

Step through the code in the debugger and check the state of the dictionary before the `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

`NullReferenceException` is thrown when `Bag<T>` can not cast to `Bag<Event>`

if you change signature to `internal void AddEvent<T>(Event ev) where T : class` exception will dismiss